# Pass function by props in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-router-v4, react-props

I know how to pass props in the react router like `string` type for example. But I have a problem when I try to pass props of function. On my children component, this props is `"undefined"`.

Exemple of my Link :

```
<Link to={'/Content/' + this.props.index + '/' + this.props.decreaseIndexProject}>Page n°1</Link>
```

The index props is a number, so I can get it on my children component, but not the `decreaseIndexProject` props.

I use PropType :

```
NavBar.propTypes = {
   indexProject: PropTypes.number,
   decreaseIndexProject: PropTypes.func
};
```

My router component :

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/Content/:index/:decrease" exact name="content" component={Content} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Maby there is an other way to pass a function ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're concatenating a function into a string? I don't get what you're trying to do

Comment: Hum I don't think, I just pass two arguments with differents type on my Router, isn't it?

Comment: No, you're trying to concatenate `index` and `decreaseIndexProject` to the string `'/Content/'`, which is impossible if `decreaseIndexProject` is a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the function as location state with Link like

```
<Link to={{
   pathname: '/Content/' + this.props.index
   state: {decrease: this.props.decreaseIndexProject}
}}>Page n°1</Link>
```

and

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/Content/:index" exact name="content" component={Content} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Now `in Content` you can use it like `this.props.location.state.decrease`

Answer (score 1):

@Shubham Khatri's answer is right but also don't forget passing the location to your component otherwise your location.state will be undefined.

```
<Route
      path="/Content/:index"
      render={props => (<ComponentName location={props.location} {...props}/>)}
 />
```