# How to pass function as prop in react routerv5 with the Link tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to pass a function from one of my components to another inside the  tag from react router.

I have three screens (`LoginScreen`, `SelectionScreen`, and `CreateScreen`) in my application. I have a function (`submit`) in the login screen that I want to pass to the create screen.

When I try to invoke the function that I have passed, I get: `TypeError: this.props.history.location.data.submitFunction is not a function`

I tried to use this answer from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60742518/how-can-i-pass-function-through-link-in-react) but it still says the same error. Let me know if you guys need anymore info. Thanks!

LoginScreen.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props)
 }
 ...

 submit = () => { // this is the function I want to pass to CreateScreen
  ... do some stuff
 }

 render(){
  return(
   <div>
    ...
    <Button color="secondary">
     <Link to={{
      pathname: "/Selection",
      state: {
       data: this.RandomData  
      },
      data: {
       submitFunction: this.submit
      }
      }}> Next Screen
     </Link>
    </Button>

   </div>

 )}
}
```

SelectionScreen.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class SelectionScreen extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {}
 }
 ...


 render(){
  return(
   <div>
    ...
    <Button color="secondary">
     <Link to={{
      pathname: "/Create",
      state: {
       data: this.props.history.location.state.data
      },
      data: {
       submitFunction: this.props.history.location.data.submitFunction
      }
      }}>Next Screen
     </Link>
    </Button>

   </div>

 )}
}
export default withRouter(SelectionScreen)
```

CreateScreen.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class CreateScreen extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {}
 }
 ...

 handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(e);
  this.props.history.location.data.submitFunction(randomData);
 }

 render(){
  return(
   <div>
    ...
    <Button color="secondary" onPress={this.handleClick}>
     Submit
    </Button>

   </div>

 )}
}
export default withRouter(CreateScreen)
```

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen.js'
import SelectionScreen from './SelectionScreen.js'
import CreateScreen from './CreateScreen.js'

export default function App() {
 return (
  <div>
   <Router>
    <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/">
      <LoginScreen />
     </Route>
     <Route exact path="/Selection">
      <SelectionScreen />
     </Route>
     <Route exact path="/Create">
      <CreateScreen />
     </Route>
    </Switch>
   </Router>
  </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: A similar question was asked here .
I think this might solve your problem 

> [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50236502/9418800][1]

You could also use **context** instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass function by props in react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50235503/pass-function-by-props-in-react-router)

Comment: I tried the solution from both those links and unfortunately I get a `DataCloneError`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the state in your example, that is why you're pointing to an undefined value and getting the error, for example your link look like this:

```
 <Link to={{
  pathname: "/Selection",
  state: {
   data: this.RandomData,
   submitFunction: this.submit,
  },
  }}> Next Screen
 </Link>
```

And then in any other component that has the react router props you need to call the submit function like this:

```
this.props.location.state.submitFunction
```

Or to call the data object

```
this.props.location.state.data
```

Keep in mind that your component should have some validation before calling that, in case you're accessing the page without using the Link component

```
 handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(e);
  if (this.props.location?.state?.submitFunction) {
   this.props.location.state.submitFunction(randomData)
  }
 }
```

Comment: I tried your edits and now I am getting no error but the function still isnt being called. Here is a sandbox as an example. https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-wing-bgww2?file=/src/LoginScreen.js

Comment: Hey sorry, your sandbox is not working for me.

Comment: Could you not load the sandbox at all? Or did you also get the `DataCloneError ` error? The `DataCloneError` is the problem I keep on running into. Any ideas? @jean182

Comment: Hey I did some research and I think that is quite odd, I will suggest to create an issue in the react-router dom project to see why that happens, because it seems that you could pass functions in later versions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50235503/pass-function-by-props-in-react-router

Comment: Also you can create another prop inside called data outside of the state prop, but I don't think is an ideal solution because you're passing something that should not be there in the Link  to prop object

Comment: I ended up lifting the state up which allowed me to just pass the function as a prop. I am still planning on opening an Issue on the react-router-dom repo. Thanks for the help!!!